# Feature Exraction in Matlab then importing into Weka

Tags: matlab, weka, activity-recognition

I have captured data from an accelerometer x,y,z. I am doing activity recognition and have separated the data into sit,run,jump.

I am now windowing the data and extracting features such as the mean, variance etc and then saving it to a features.txt file,then I am going to import the data into Weka software to be classified.

I am looking for help on the file structure to be imported into Weka as I am not sure which one is correct for use with Weka.

Should the features be stored in one txt file or seperate?

Do they need their own columns: mean_x mean_y mean_z var_x var_y var_z Label? or the setup I have below?

Example of Weka:

```
   @relation datashimmer
    @attribute x numeric

@attribute y numeric

@attribute z numeric

}@attribute class { sitmean, jumpmean ,  runmean, sitstd, jumpstd, runstd, sitvar, jumpvar, runvar, sitrange, jumprange, runrange


@data
   9.0706440e+00   7.8577383e-01   2.4532359e+00   jumpmean
   9.6451465e+00   7.8731349e-01   3.1504403e+00   jumpmean
   8.1915240e+00   9.9549126e-01   2.4723417e+00   jumpmean
   8.6773829e+00   6.3727150e-01   3.0240603e+00   jumpmean
   8.6675553e+00   7.3380330e-01   3.0251476e+00   jumpmean
   8.6544917e+00   8.4768398e-01   2.8385212e+00   jumpmean
   9.5032030e+00   1.1324107e+00   2.1942181e+00   jumpmean
   9.5477273e+00   1.0467068e+00   2.0262543e+00   runmean
   9.5686235e+00   1.1320179e+00   1.8989209e+00   runmean
   9.2875020e+00   8.6683897e-01   1.9064545e+00   runmean
   9.3515172e+00   9.2082513e-01   2.2105460e+00   runmean
   9.6041949e+00   9.2349286e-01   2.5863699e+00   runmean
   9.6029677e+00   7.4794280e-01   2.3176337e+00   runmean
   9.1105362e+00   9.0374931e-01   2.1625089e+00   runmean
  -5.0683414e-01  -4.4845132e+00   8.8514156e+00  sitmean
  -4.9025531e-01  -4.4989652e+00   8.8622800e+00  sitmean
  -4.9871921e-01  -4.4879779e+00   8.8922710e+00  sitmean
  -5.0798669e-01  -4.4828028e+00   8.8459366e+00  sitmean
  -5.4927840e-01  -4.4699890e+00   8.8474149e+00  sitmean
  -5.3211037e-01  -4.4591018e+00   8.8433826e+00  sitmean
  -5.5223809e-01  -4.4869555e+00   8.8594771e+00  sitmean
  -4.7530904e-01  -4.4812295e+00   8.8135292e+00  sitmean
  -5.4696903e-01  -4.4788825e+00   8.8484514e+00  sitmean
  -5.5149171e-01  -4.4587802e+00   8.8630469e+00  sitmean
  -5.3465224e-01  -4.4478393e+00   8.8383810e+00  sitmean
  -5.1742062e-01  -4.4637259e+00   8.8325696e+00  sitmean
  -5.4154869e-01  -4.4833639e+00   8.8562804e+00  sitmean
  -5.7514668e-01  -4.4912760e+00   8.8727185e+00  sitmean
   9.3696539e+00   1.1837913e+00  -2.6525999e+00   jumpmean
   8.6643644e+00   1.2731911e+00  -2.4803529e+00   jumpmean
   8.0837365e+00   1.9774159e+00  -2.8276019e+00   jumpmean
   8.0305034e+00   1.2057473e+00  -1.9911895e+00   jumpmean
   7.9512264e+00   4.5797049e+00  -8.0403707e-01   jumpmean
   8.5823014e+00   3.9339561e+00  -2.6684712e+00   jumpmean
   8.2940896e+00   2.1376560e+00  -2.7870077e+00   jumpmean
   9.4819739e+00   8.1379138e-01  -3.1084057e+00   runmean
   9.0599416e+00   3.9622206e-01  -3.4679528e+00   runmean
   9.3782963e+00   9.4021813e-01  -3.3614160e+00   runmean
   9.4959636e+00   8.3451458e-01  -3.0700251e+00   runmean
   9.3596252e+00   7.6187722e-01  -3.3890264e+00   runmean
   9.4984387e+00   1.1694115e+00  -3.3733935e+00   runmean
   8.9490648e+00   1.4501386e+00  -3.1231425e+00   runmean
   8.3033044e+00  -8.7385271e-01   4.9949720e+00  sitmean
   8.2657411e+00  -9.2072139e-01   5.0284777e+00  sitmean
   8.2039554e+00  -9.1552295e-01   5.1517434e+00  sitmean
   8.2272207e+00  -8.4401430e-01   5.1535285e+00  sitmean
   8.2654827e+00  -7.9834045e-01   5.0608142e+00  sitmean
   8.2999421e+00  -8.6703733e-01   5.0902732e+00  sitmean
   8.2944043e+00  -8.0556494e-01   5.0225056e+00  sitmean
   8.5033422e+00   3.0787253e+00   3.5076829e+00   jumpstd
   7.6895407e+00   3.1243470e+00   3.0559549e+00   jumpstd
   7.5029557e+00   4.0664196e+00   4.1725267e+00   jumpstd
   7.5436436e+00   4.3278471e+00   3.8818316e+00   jumpstd
   6.1032521e+00   4.6354434e+00   3.5036980e+00   jumpstd
   7.4142339e+00   4.0956300e+00   3.7602181e+00   jumpstd
   7.9337673e+00   3.2664252e+00   4.2575543e+00   jumpstd
   5.0545343e+00   2.8901073e+00   3.5430258e+00   runstd
   5.3394208e+00   2.1666505e+00   3.7298383e+00   runstd
   4.8233755e+00   3.0923609e+00   3.4364285e+00   runstd
   5.3904459e+00   2.6258827e+00   3.3256969e+00   runstd
   4.3812033e+00   2.7708500e+00   2.5985276e+00   runstd
   4.1402607e+00   4.0070005e+00   2.7039632e+00   runstd
   4.2720294e+00   4.6312551e+00   4.4228231e+00   runstd
   2.7539715e-01   2.3209201e-01   3.2587558e-01   sitstd
   1.5065993e-01   1.7074749e-01   1.7440757e-01   sitstd
   1.6740466e-01   1.5952978e-01   1.6872027e-01   sitstd
   1.6208795e-01   1.6157018e-01   1.5045205e-01   sitstd
   1.8287180e-01   1.7500556e-01   1.9729539e-01   sitstd
   1.8928747e-01   1.9478179e-01   1.4550928e-01   sitstd
   1.7755868e-01   1.7635119e-01   1.4697588e-01   sitstd
```

My matlab code:

```
%WindowParams
Fq = 51.2;
%Sample Rate of Shimmer
windowLength = 2;
%Length for each window in seconds
startPos = 1;
startPos2 = 1;
startPos3 = 1;
%Starting Position for 1st win
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
endPos2 = startPos2 + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
endPos3= startPos3 + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
%End Position for 1st win
totalWindows = floor(length(martySit)/Fq/windowLength);
totalWindows2 = floor(length(martyJump)/Fq/windowLength);
totalWindows3 = floor(length(martyRun)/Fq/windowLength);
stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

for i = 1:totalWindows
    eprange = range(martySit(startPos:endPos,:));%calculate window range
    martySitfeatures (i,1:3) = eprange; %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    %Next window position
    startPos = endPos+1;
    endPos= startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martySitfeatures (:,4) = 10;
end
for i = 1:totalWindows2
    eprange = range(martyJump(startPos2:endPos2,:));
    %calculate window range
    %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    martyJumpfeatures (i,1:3) = eprange;
    %Next window position
    startPos2 = endPos2+1;
    endPos2 = startPos2+ (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martyJumpfeatures (:,4) = 11;
end

for i = 1:totalWindows3
    eprange = range(martyRun(startPos3:endPos3,:));
    %calculate window range
    %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    martyRunfeatures (i,1:3) = eprange;
    %Next window position
    startPos3 = endPos3+1;
    endPos3 = startPos3+ (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martyRunfeatures (:,4) = 12;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either import `csv` files or `arff` files. The default format to import data in Weka being the `arff` format.

The details for the `arff` format is described [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29).

You can basically just add the following header:

```
@RELATION movement

@ATTRIBUTE x  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE y  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE z  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE class        {sit,run,jump}

@data

[x array] [y array] [z array] [class array]
```

If you want to add the mean information as an attribute:

```
@RELATION movement

@ATTRIBUTE mean_x  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE mean_y  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE mean_z  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE x  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE y  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE z  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE class        {sit,run,jump}

@data

[mean_x array] [mean_y array] [mean_z array] [x array] [y array] [z array] [class array]
```

Then just save it as a txt file with the .arff extension.